# webpack reference erro window.location.hostname cannot be found, vue.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli-3, http-proxy-middleware

Any help would be really appreciated on this issue.

I want to set the proxy target dynamically inside webpack index.js

```
proxyTable: {
    '/api': {
    target: 'http://' +  window.location.hostname.split('.')[0] + '.example.com',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/api': ''
    }
  }
},
```

and webpack is giving error ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: What is your webpack target?

Comment: That code is run in Node.js, during the webpack build stage. It is not run in the browser, where the `window` global is available.